# Custom window switcher shortcut changes back to default on logon

Tags: unity, 16.04

I have changed the default shortcut for switching between windows of a program from <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> in **ccsm**, but after each login it reverts to the default <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>

### Solutions I've tried:

- Use `dconf-editor` to change:

  - `org.compiz.profiles.unity.plugins.unityshell.alt-tab-next-window` to `<Super>grave`
  - `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings.switch-group` to `<Super>Above_Tab`
- Used `unity-tweak-tool`